# error during loadig JDBC driver

Tags: java, ms-access

```
try {
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("Error loading driver " + e);
}
```

but the netbeans giving the error that

unreported exception  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;must be caught or declared to  be thrown
and the other two error are at the start of try block and catch block that is

illegal start of type
so what may be the problem please guide me about tis

Comment: I believe you have declared this block outside a function definition. Can you paste the code for your class.

Answer (score 0):

May be something wrong with other part of your code. Please double check your code.

```
public class Sample
{
  public static void main(String []args)
   {
     try {
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
       System.out.println("Error loading driver "+e);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot more consideration needed to your code rather than just putting in `Class.forName`. 
You may refer to example below as a start up:

[JdbcOdbcDriver](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/Listtablesinadatabase.htm)